# Get the value of the checked checkbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, checkbox

I am currently developing a web app. I have 10 checkboxes inside my form.

How can I grab the values of the currently selected checkboxes?

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="Wifi" name="wifi"><i class="fa fa-wifi fa-lg"></i> Wifi Internet
 <input type="checkbox" value="kitchen" name="kitchen"><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-lg"></i> Kitchen
 ....
```

Comment: You should start with https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ at least .. there are many handy examples to understand the very basics. Before asking you should try yourself and show us at least some effort solving your problem... Fingers crossed.

Comment: Hello! I edited your question to remove unnecessary information about the DB storage and to clarify what you are actually trying to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`ng-model`s](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D).

```
<input ng-model="wifi" type="checkbox" value="Wifi" name="wifi">
<input ng-model="kitchen" type="checkbox" value="kitchen" name="kitchen">
..etc
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.wifi // true or false
$scope.kitchen // true or false
```

Once you have these values in your controller, you can send the checkbox data to a server to do with as it wishes.